# I asked a question, and would like to give an answer that which advocates against a possible solution

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-format

Here is the question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/504413/what-is-the-fastest-two-way-sync-framework-available-on-ubuntu

I would like to post as an answer, **WHY** rsync should **NOT** be considered. The reason why I would like to do this, is because people who are researching sync solutions on Ubuntu will likely consider RSync. This will help them narrow their search.

Would this be acceptable on the Ubuntu Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

You lost me at "Hypothetical Situation".

This site is more about solving practical problems that people face regularly every day, not satisfying intellectual curiosity on syncing algorithms. (Though that is an interesting question, I just don't think it's AU material.)

Comment: True enough. I have a hard time with Stack Exchange, in that I do not know how to ask; "What are all the two way syncing frameworks available on ubuntu?" ; I have the feeling that it would get shut down as being too open ended, or that there is no answer to it, or that it promotes discussion. And so instead, I ask for the "fastest", figuring that I will get the most answers that way. What do you think?